# Set an attribute value in multishop system

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm making a cronjob which sets values for a custom global attribute with attribute code 'color_family'. The value that is given is an array (for example $color_families = array(211, 215, 216, 228)), because the type of 'color_family' is "multiple select".

My code for setting the value:

```
$_product->setData('color_family', $color_families);
$_product->save();
```

My problem is, that this works only for one store system. When I run the cronjob on multishop system, the value for this attribute is not updated.

I found this online and tried it:

```
foreach($_product->getStoreIds() as $storeId) {
    $_product->setStoreId($storeId)
         ->setData('color_family', $color_families);
    $_product->save();
}
```

but that also brought no result.

I'm working on Magento CE v. 1.7.0.2..

I would really appreciate any advice you could give me.

Answer (score 4):

You can update attribute values in an other way:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($productIds, $productData, $storeId);
```

Let's take an example:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array(12, 33), array('color_family'=>'211,215,216,228'), 0);
```

This means that the products with ids 12 and 33 will have the attribute 'color_family' changed to the value '211,215,216,228' for the store id 0 (admin). Since your attribute is global, this should do. You can change one or more products at a time.

Comment: Marius, thank you for your reply.
The problem was that I was getting the wrong attribute ids for 'color_family'. There was nothing wrong with my code. And because the ids were not found, could also not be set.

Comment: :). Anyway. You can use the code above. It's faster than saving a product through the Magento internal API.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up that bit about store id=0 for global attributes.